# Quit Application in Java Script?

Tags: javascript

i need to quit application as soon as stop button pressed from HTML.The start and stop button working fine but the problem with stop button is that it pause the game not quit the application. i wrote this code in else block `window.setTimeout(animloop, 1000);` it will pause the game but not quit the game or if i use `windows.close()` it will close browser immediately .

my code:

```
    var gameStarted = false;
    // Infinte loop for game play
      (function animloop() {
        if (gameStarted) {
          requestAnimFrame(animloop);
          render();
        } else {
          window.setTimeout(animloop, 1000); // check the state per second
        }
      })(); // ends (function animloop() )
    }); // ends $(doc).ready
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="./arrows/clubbackground.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsRev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>DDR-Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="BackgroundScene">
  <div id="DanceScoreboard">
    <div id="GameStopped"><button id="StartBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=true;">Begin Game</button>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="Status">Click Begin Game to start</div>
    </div>
    <div id="GameRunning"><button id="StopBtn" class="btnStyle" onclick="gameStarted=false;">Stop Game</button>
      <div id="Status" class="Status"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="dancePoints" class="Points">Points Earned:
      <div class="OutputText" id="CorrectCount">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stage"></div>
  <!-- ENDS .STAGE -->
  <div id="controls">
    <img id="left" src="./arrows/staticLeft.png">
    <img id="up" src="./arrows/staticUp.png">
    <img id="down" src="./arrows/staticDown.png">
    <img id="right" src="./arrows/staticRight.png">
  </div>
  <!-- ENDS #CONTROLS -->

</body>
</html>
```

java script code:

```
var notes = [];
var gameStarted = false;
var Score = 0;

// ==== CLASS FOR ARROWS ==== //

// 1. Direction of arrows
// 2. jQuery img that links to direction bottom
// 3. Destroy when it arrow gets to the 
// 4. Explode when arrow gets to the bottom

// Class Arrow
function Arrow(direction) {
  // CSS spacings for the arrows //
  var xPos = null;

  switch (direction) {
    case "left":
      xPos = "350px";
      break;
    case "up":
      xPos = "420px";
      break;
    case "down":
      xPos = "490px";
      break;
    case "right":
      xPos = "560px";
      break;
  }

  this.direction = direction;
  this.image = $("<img src='./arrows/" + direction + ".gif'/>");
  this.image.css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: "0px",
    left: xPos
  });
  $('.stage').append(this.image);

} // ends CLASS Arrow

// To enable animating the arrows
Arrow.prototype.step = function() {
  // Controls the speed of the arrows
  this.image.css("top", "+=4px");
};

// Deletes arrows when they get to bottom of page
Arrow.prototype.destroy = function() {
  // removes the image of the DOM
  this.image.remove();
  // Removes the note/arrow from memory/array
  notes.splice(0, 1);
};

// Explodes arrow when hit
Arrow.prototype.explode = function() {
  this.image.remove();
};



// For random arrows
var randNum = 0;

// Frame increasing
var frame = 0;

// Determines the speed of notes
var arrowSpawnRate = 40;


// Random generator for arrows
function randomGen() {
  // Randomizes between 1 and 4
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  if (randNum === 1) {
    notes.push(new Arrow("left"));
  }
  if (randNum === 2) {
    notes.push(new Arrow("right"));
  }
  if (randNum === 3) {
    notes.push(new Arrow("up"));
  }
  if (randNum === 4) {
    notes.push(new Arrow("down"));
  }
} // ends randomGen()

// Render function //
function render() {
  if (frame++ % arrowSpawnRate === 0) {
    randomGen();
  }

  // Animate arrows showering down //
  for (var i = notes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    notes[i].step();
    // Check for cleanup
    if (notes[i].image.position().top > 615) {
      notes[i].destroy();
    }
  }
} // ends render()

// jQuery to animate arrows //
$(document).ready(function() {
  // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 40 / 75);
      };
  })();

  /*  place the rAF *before* the render() 
      to assure as close to 60fps with the 
      setTimeout fallback.                    */

  // Infinte loop for game play
  (function animloop() {
    if (gameStarted) {
      requestAnimFrame(animloop);
      render();
    } else {
      window.setTimeout(animloop, 1000); // check the state per second
    }
  })(); // ends (function animloop() )
}); // ends $(doc).ready



// Listening for when the key is pressed
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37 && notes[i].direction == "left") {
      if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {
        console.log("LEFT! " + notes[i].explode());
        Score++;
        score();
      }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38 && notes[i].direction == "up") {
      if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {
        console.log("UP! " + notes[i].explode());
        Score++;
        score();
      }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40 && notes[i].direction == "down") {
      if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {
        console.log("DOWN! " + notes[i].explode());
        Score++;
        score();
      }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39 && notes[i].direction == "right") {
      if (notes[i].image.position().top > 490 && notes[i].image.position().top < 730) {
        console.log("RIGHT! " + notes[i].explode());
        Score++;
        score();
      }
    }
  } // ends loop
}); // ends $(doc).keyup

function score() {
  document.querySelector(".Points").textContent = Score;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "quit the application"? It's just a web page, it's either open or it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar i mean close the browser

Comment: You said you didn't want to close the browser.

Comment: But you can only call `window.close()` if the application opened the window, not if the user opened the window.

Comment: @Barmar my game is browser so i have two button on it 1 for start playing and 2nd for stop. The stop button pause the game on browser what i need it quit the browser.

Comment: JavaScript can't close the browser. Just stop changing the window, and let the user close the window.

Comment: @Barmar check i update my post ok i got it how should i implement when i press stop button it refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "quit the application" mean?

You can close the browser window, or redirect the user to another route.

But the exact semantics of "quit the application" for your game in the browser need to be defined.

If you mean "Close the web browser", then you need to have your game open in a new window from the game code when it starts, so that it can close the window when it finishes.

So you have a launcher page, and that opens the game in a new window. You can then communicate between the windows, and close the child window later.

See [here](https://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-parent.php) for an example of opening a child window. And [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/closing-a-window-with-javascript-beeec56344bb) for closing it. And [here](https://usefulangle.com/post/4/javascript-communication-parent-child-window) for communicating between them.

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question. I asked the same question above.

Comment: @josh Wulf i mean close the browser